# Git: redo merge with a different branch

Tags: git, merge

I have a long-running git fork and I wanted to merge the upstream branch. Unfortunately I did `git merge upstream-topic` and spent hours resolving merge conflicts before realizing I really wanted to do `git merge upstream-master`.

The branches have 99% the same content, except `upstream-topic` has a bunch of merge commits from merging `upstream-master` that I'd prefer not to have cluttering the history forever. Is there any way to "redo" the merge with `upstream-master` without losing all my conflict resolution?

I've just discovered `git rerere` and really wish I'd had it enabled :(

Comment: How are `upstream-topic` and `upstream-master` related?  Is one branch ahead of the other?

Comment: Are `upstream-topic` and `upstream-master` really identical except for those extra merge commits? Like when you diff using `git diff upstream-topic upstream-master` you don’t get any difference?

Comment: `upstream-master` is slightly ahead, and `upstream-topic` has a couple other minor commits that I don't really care about (shouldn't cause conflicts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two branches `upstream-topic` and `upstream-master` really contain the same content and only differ in those extra merge commits, then you can simply reuse the content of your merged `upstream-topic` to solve the merge conflicts in `upstream-master`:

```
# save the current master which merged upstream-topic
git branch merged-topic

# reset master to its original commit
git reset --hard origin/master

# do the merge, getting lots of conflicts
git merge upstream-master

# instead of solving those conflicts again, just use all the contents
# of your already merged topic
git checkout merged-topic -- .

# check the status, resolve the conflicts, and commit
git status
git add -u .
git commit
```

Comment: This almost works, but there are other changes on upstream-topic. Perhaps only checking out the conflicted files would do the trick

Comment: Yes, you can of course customize what you want to check out. You can also try generating a patch using `git diff upstream-topic upstream-master` that gives you the changes necessary to get from the topic to master; so you could try to apply that patch after checking out the merged topic to generate the merged master. (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: Once I removed the extraneous commits, this worked like a charm! Thanks!